# Does on-premise ADFS support OpenID Connect?

Tags: active-directory, openid, adfs, openid-connect

I'm trying to figure out, if it's possible to authenticate via an on-premise ADFS, using OpenID Connect?

I wasn't able to find any examples on that - is this scenario supported? Or should I federate ADFS with AAD?

Comment: does anyone have any ideas? Is it possible without introducing any additional elements like ThinkTecture Authorization Server?

Comment: I'm using ADFS 3.0 but I needed OpenID Connect to authenticate users using SPA apps. I decided to use WSO2 Identity Server + WSO2 Api Manager federated with ADFS to get the OpenIdConnect support

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, ADFS 1.0/2.0 do not support OpenID Connect.

Update: the newest version of ADFS i.e. ADFS 2016 does.

Answer (score 2):

As of Windows Server 2016 RTM - OpenID Connect is now fully supported.